# Packages Not Found Error: Not available from current channel- Bioconda

Tags: python, installation, conda, bioinformatics, apple-m1

Using a Mac with M1 chip, I'm trying to install the following Bioconda packages:

```
cutadapt  
trim-galore  
samtools  
bedtools.  
htseq.   
bowtie2.    
deeptools.  
macs2
```

I've been able to install `picard` and `fastqc` with no issues, but all others turn out one of two error messages:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
```

or

```
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                          

UnsatisfiableError:
```

I do have the correct channels though:

```
conda config --show channels 
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
```

Not sure how to fix this

Comment: How did you install Conda? Bioconda doesn't support native M1 yet, so if want to use it, you'd need to install an `osx-64` Miniforge build and run it in x86_64 emulation mode (via Rosetta2).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72678631/967621

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed the issue like this:

1. Install Rosetta2 by running `softwareupdate --install-rosetta`
2. Download the x86-64 bit version of miniconda instead of the M1 version