# conda creation NGS environment, sra-tools fastqc multiqc samtools bowtie2 hisat2 subread

Tags: installation, anaconda, conda, bioinformatics, apple-m1

I cannot easily create an environment with conda containing the NGS tools I want. I reinstalled conda to get a fresh start since I had many python packages in the base env. I also took the occasion to install the full anaconda3 instead of miniconda I had before now I have way enough space.

Although all the packages are available via bioconda the only 2 i can add to my env are fastqc and multiqc. Before that I could install sra-tools and fastqc in the base env with miniconda3.

**Config:** MacOS Monterey 12.1 M1 chip. migration from my old macbook air with the lastest time machine bkp. I uninstalled miniconda with the anaconda-clean procedure and after that I also removed a python 3.9.5 I had in the apps folder I had initially installed to start learning 1yr ago before knowing about conda.

**Also to be mentioned in case it may help:** anaconda-navigator was not installed by the Anaconda3-2022.05-MacOSX-arm64.pkg (sha256 integrity check was ok)
in following the check installation/navigator troubleshooting on anaconda website I came across an error upon launching spyder:

````
```(ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets')```
````

Does somebody know where this unability to find the packages comes?

Thank you for your help!
best, Daniel

**Env creation command and console output:**

```
(base) mymac:~ D________$ conda create --name ngstools fastqc multiqc sra-tools samtools bowtie2 hisat2 subread -c conda-forge -c bioconda -c bioconda/label/cf201901
```

Terminal output:

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done

Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- hisat2
- subread
- bowtie2
- samtools
- sra-tools

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/osx-arm64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/label/cf201901/osx-arm64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/label/cf201901/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're looking for, navigate to
https://anaconda.org
and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Prefatory Comments

That is not a configuration I would recommend to bioinformatics users with M1 machines at the moment. There is no support yet for **osx-arm64** in Bioconda. I expect one would find the least configuration issues by having everything in emulation (**osx-64**) from the **base**. Or you can continue with the **osx-arm64** base (as you have now), but create new environments with [the `subdir` setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70219965/570918). The answer below shows steps in this direction.

Also, I would very much avoid Anaconda/Miniconda. [Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge) base is what I recommend to all bioinformaticians. And [set the Bioconda channels globally](https://bioconda.github.io/user/install.html#set-up-channels).

Lastly, only advanced users should use channel labels (e.g., `bioconda/label/cf201901`). I realize they automatically show up on Anaconda Cloud, but they are only ever applicable in specialized circumstances, which most users will never encounter.

---

### Immediate workaround

If you want to keep the **osx-arm64** base, then you'll need to create a **osx-64** environment for the NGS tools. I recommend the following protocol for best practice:

```bash
## create empty environment
conda create -n ngstools

## activate environment
conda activate ngstools

## configure architecture
conda config --env --set subdir osx-64

## configure channels for Bioconda
conda config --env --add channels defaults
conda config --env --add channels bioconda
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge

## install packages
conda install fastqc multiqc sra-tools samtools bowtie2 hisat2 subread
```

It's convoluted and, until **osx-arm64** sees full support, you'd have to do this for every environment that requires emulation and Bioconda. Hence, why I recommend instead that you reinstall a **osx-64** base (Miniforge), which would just work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer. I could try both suggestions as I don't need to create a lot of environments, I am just currently practicing through the whole RNAseq analysis workflow

Comment: osx-64 vs arm 64: I first tried the  anaconda...osx-64.pkg installer which would not be executed before I remembered the M1 machines needed arm64. However the osx-64 miniconda that came from the migration of my old OS X 10.13 seemed to work, at least to install python modules (seaborn, sickit-learn, pydotplus, openpyxl). Will mambaforge osx-64 be allowed to be installed then?

Comment: Yes, I’ve tested it.

Comment: It indeed seems to work so far, thank you very much!