# Installing bowtie2 from miniconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I recently bought a Mac and I just installed miniconda (Miniconda3 macOS Apple M1 64-bit pkg). However, when I try to install bowtie2 (conda install -c bioconda bowtie2), I get this message:

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- bowtie2

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/osx-arm64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch

However, the package looks to be in bioconda:

https://anaconda.org/bioconda/bowtie2

What is the problem there? I can install other packages with no further issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conda creation NGS environment, sra-tools fastqc multiqc samtools bowtie2 hisat2 subread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72678631/conda-creation-ngs-environment-sra-tools-fastqc-multiqc-samtools-bowtie2-hisat2)

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I couldn't install it using Miniconda3 macOS Apple M1 64-bit pkg, but I could install it with the Miniconda3 macOS Intel x86 64-bit pkg...

Comment: You don't have to change your **base** install of Conda, only the `subdir` on the environment you create. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72679307/570918